# Доступ к админке

Tags: php, безопасность

Есть небольшая страница, где юзер может выполнять различные запросы к БД. 
Сделал так. На одной странице создал форму с инпутом. В инпут юзер вбивает пароль, пароль сравнивается с паролем с БД, если все ок, то открывает страницу.

Скажите, насколько безопасна такая система? Легко ли взломать ее?
И какие есть приемы сделать эту страницу более безопасной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что md5 не раз была дискредитирована как криптостойкая хэш-функция.
Существуют и относительно несложны методы нахождения в ней коллизий, существуют таблицы md5-хэшей, в том числе в свободном доступе, - не всех возможных конечно, но тем не менее - простые пароли раскалывает как орех.

Пароли в чистом виде хранить в БД не рекомендуется. Можно использовать соль - присоленная md5 это уже лучше, особенно если солить грамотно.

На php.net для криптования паролей рекомендуют сейчас crypt(). Существует также функция sha1() - более стойкая благодаря более медленному алгоритму и более длинному хэшу. Она была скомпрометирована в меньшей степени, но, сторого говоря, и она не является достаточно надежной. Но уже грамотно присолив ее можно получить для рядовых задач достаточную защиту.
Мне кстати, если интересно, нравится такой примерно способ:

```
if (function_exists('hash') && in_array('whirlpool', hash_algos()) {
$hash = hash('whirlpool', $pass . sha1($pass));
} else {
$hash = // something else
}
```

А вообще тема очень обширная.

Answer (score 1):

Сложно что-то сказать, не видя кода. Но раз вы пароль ищете в БД, то сразу же появляется вероятность SQL-инъекций. Экранируйте запросы, а лучше используйте PDO для доступа к базе.

Вообще, SQL-инъекция - самый вероятный вариант. Другие варианты:

- эксплоиты - ошибки в реализаци PHP, используются взломщиками для совершения противоестественных действий с системой. Тут вы вряд ли что-то сможете сделать, только обновиться до версии, на которой эксплоит не воспроизводитя.
- плохой пароль. Если пароль тупо подбирается по словарю, а на сайте нет защиты от брутфорса, то злоумышленник получит доступ к вашему сайту достаточно быстро.
- отсутствие защиты от DDoS - ваш сервер загрузят мусорными запросами. Это не совсем взлом, но доступ к сайту вы получить не сможете.

Ещё: ваш сайт состоит из одной страницы? Подумайте, что будет, если вам потребуется защитиить от произвольного доступа несколько страниц. Не будете же вы копипастить этот код на несколько страниц.

Comment: Не будете же вы копипастить этот код на несколько страниц.
Страница одна, паролей много.

Comment: Не совсем понял ваш комментарий. Особенно выражение "Страница одна, паролей много". Вы же вроде из базы пароли тащите?

Answer (score 0):

Добавь еще логин - брут усложнится в разы. Пароль в БД в MD5 храни, фильтр инпута, как написал товарищ выше. Чистый РНР я так понимаю? Если то что запаролено очень важно, можно попробовать на фреймверке это реализовать. В БД храни кол-во неудачных попыток ввода с одного ip, по достижении предела - блок ip, или интервал между попытками. От эксплоитов, соглашусь, конечно, вряд ли что спасет, жаль кода не видно, но это не мешает самому поискать уязвимостей на просторах гугла и затем исправить их у себя.

Comment: Лучше пароль хранить не в MD5, а в BlowFish.

Comment: Лучше пароль хранить не в MD5, а в BlowFish.

А для меня это новое, поясните, пожалуйста, чем же BF лучше MD5? Для MD5 в MySQL хотя бы есть встроенная функция.